# Optimize mysql query using various join and order by rand()

Tags: mysql, database, join, random, explain

I was having trouble on my site, so I went look into mysql slow query log.

Fixed some indexing and also querys without joins now the server load got lower and its running fine.

I still have a query that I havent been able to fix, if any of you have a tip so I can make it better, I would appreciated it.

This is the query

```
SELECT p.product_id,
          p.product_offer_price,
          ps.subcategory_name,
          pb.brand_name,
          pm.model_name,
          pm.display_name,
          pm.year_from,
          pm.year_to 
        FROM product p
        INNER JOIN product_subcategory ps ON ps.subcategory_id = p.product_subcategory_id AND ps.subcategory_category_id = 12
        INNER JOIN product_stock pq ON pq.product_id = p.product_id AND pq.product_quantity > 0
        INNER JOIN product_photos pp ON pp.product_id = p.product_id
        INNER JOIN product_brand pb ON pb.brand_id = p.product_brand_id
        INNER JOIN product_model pm ON pm.model_id = p.product_model_id
        GROUP BY p.product_id
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

This is what explain shows about the query
[image: https://imgur.com/a/LpIJe]

I was trying to accomplish something like this, but doesn't work

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_offer_price, ps.subcategory_name, pb.brand_name, pm.model_name, pm.display_name, pm.year_from, pm.year_to
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_subcategory ps ON ps.subcategory_id = p.product_subcategory_id
AND ps.subcategory_category_id =12
INNER JOIN product_stock pq ON pq.product_id = p.product_id
AND pq.product_quantity >0
INNER JOIN product_photos pp ON pp.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN product_brand pb ON pb.brand_id = p.product_brand_id
INNER JOIN product_model pm ON pm.model_id = p.product_model_id
WHERE p.product_id >= FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * (
SELECT MAX( product_id )
FROM product ) )
GROUP BY p.product_id
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` tends to be slow and is hard to optimize.

Comment: It won't affect performance, but conditions on a single table column should be in `WHERE`, not `ON`. Except for `LEFT JOIN`, you should only have relationships between the tables being joined in `ON`.

Comment: @Barmar I know and I have fixed other querys applying this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function now the query on top uses various JOIN so I need to figure out a way or an example to make it better.

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the foreign keys?

Comment: What does EXPLAIN show for the query? Do you have indexes on the columns used in the ON and WHERE clauses?

Comment: @SloanThrasher all joins are index

Comment: What does EXPLAIN show about the query?

Comment: @SloanThrasher https://imgur.com/a/LpIJe

Comment: @Barmar is most likely correct about *RAND()* slowing the query. FYI, you should edit the question and put the image there instead of in a comment.

Comment: @SloanThrasher updated the question with some more info. thx

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.