# How can i optimize this mysql query to be faster when it comes to thousands of rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just started my website, and after 5 days it slowed down, it took nearly 30 seconds to load the website, because the mysql database got bigger with plus 50-60k rows.

I have searched hours for solution, but i did not find anything that i could implement to optimize my query.

```
$idstack = $_SESSION['ids'];
      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
      maps.id,
      maps.name,
      maps.date,
      maps.mcversion,
      maps.mapid,
      maps.description,
      maps.java,
      maps.bedrock,
      maps.schematic,
      users.username,
      users.rank,
      users.verified,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.mapid = maps.id) AS likes,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downloads WHERE downloads.mapid = maps.id) AS downloads,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE views.mapid = maps.id) AS views
      FROM maps
      INNER JOIN users 
      ON maps.userid = users.id
      WHERE maps.id NOT IN ( '" . implode( "', '" , (array)$idstack ) . "' ) ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 15");

      $stmt->execute();

      $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

This query returns what i want, but it is slow when the database has thousands of rows. Any idea how could i optimize it?

Comment: Try `explain <your query>;` and share the output. Sub-selects are typically not performant.

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function looks relevant for a start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your query, you want indexes on:

- `likes(mapid)`
- `downloads(mapid)`
- `views(mapid)`
- `maps(id, userid)`
- `users(id)`

You may already have some of these indexes, if the columns are declared as primary keys.

That said, the query might still be hard to optimize.  `NOT IN` with `ORDER BY` is going to be tricky.

These are created as:

```
create index idx_likes_mapid on likes(mapid);
```

and so on.

Comment: Im kind of new to sql, can you give me an example of "indexes"?

Comment: @DominikBalogh try reading this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp