# Selecting Random Rows in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I am developing a quiz website, and I have a database which stores all of the questions.
There are different types of quizzes, like math, science, history, etc. All of the questions are stored in one table.

My questions table looks like this:

```
questions ( qno(int)  ,type(int), question, .... ,... )
```

`qno` is the primary key, and `type` is used to keep track of the quiz type.:

```
if type = 1 (math)
 type = 2(science)
```

Now, I want to select some random questions for each type of test. 
For example, I may want to select some random 20 questions for only the math test.

Does MySQL have some way to select random rows?

Comment: dup of [How to request a random row in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19412/), [quick selection of a random row from a large table in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/211329/90527).

Comment: [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4329447/6521116)

Answer (score 37):

You can use the [`rand`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function in MySQL to order the rows, and then take the top 10 (or however many you want) with `limit`.

```
select * from table order by rand() limit 10
```

If you want just the math questions:

```
select * from table where type = 1 order by rand() limit 10
```

Comment: see i want to show user one question at a time. So i am thinking is that i will use the above query when the quiz starts and then i will store all the question no in session and then i will fectch each question by using a new quesry every time . Is it right approach?

Comment: If you want just one question per page, just do `limit 1` instead of `limit 10`.

Comment: Store the questions that that user has seen in a table and then construct this query left joining to that table and where the seen table's field is null.

Comment: You can use php sessions to maintain a history of questions asked in that session. Each time you query for random question, add a "WHERE QuestionID NOT IN ( previously_asked_question_ids )" clause.

Answer (score 4):

Add a column to your table that will hold a UNIX timestamp.

Once a day or any timeframe which works for you, you run a query that updates that column.

In this case your query should run at midnight and look something like this.

```
UPDATE table SET rand_id = (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + (RAND() * 86400));
```

Then to retrieve the rows, you use a query similar to this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE rand_id > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY rand_id ASC LIMIT 20
```

Using a column with a pre-determined random value saves you needing to run a randomization function for every single row in the table for every single request to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to generate a [random permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation), store this in a session (or just the part you need, the algorithm is easily adaptable), and fetch the questions when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

To select a random number of rows with possible duplicates

```
Select Cus_Id from Customer
Where Cus_Id in (
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % (select COUNT(*) from Customer) - 0 AS Random FROM Customer)
```

If you want to start from certain point (id 1500 and above to narrower range

```
Select Cus_Id from Customer
Where Cus_Id in (
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % (select COUNT(*)+1500 from Customer) - 1300 AS Random FROM Customer)
```

If you want less you can add SELECT TOP x or TOP x PERCENT