# Select random rows from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting Random Rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283640/selecting-random-rows-in-mysql)

I'm creating a simple web application using PHP and MySQL. In it, I need to randomly select a small set of rows from a table in a random order. How can I achieve such thing using MySQL?

Comment: Please search before asking questions. Searching the exact title of your question yields [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283640) and many other similar questions.

Comment: [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4329396/6521116)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

Edit:

Useful information about the MySQL RAND() function can be found [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-rand-function.php).

Comment: Ouch... I've got > 500M rows!  That's a bit slow...

Comment: There are other performant options, if you have a sequential primary key, precompute a range of IDs in your language of choice and do a `SELECT ... WHERE id IN(x)`

Comment: Query `select count(*) from users;` returns 10293453. Query `SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;` runs 5 sec.

Comment: Just found your solution. Thank you for it. It's incredible easy and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: your solution works, but it gets slow when you have over millions of rows at your table.
So, I suggest to generate a random number in php and send it to sql query.

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from table order by rand() limit 10
```

Note that `order by rand()` with large dataset is very slow but in your case it's not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

you could do that using RAND() function .

```
SELECT questine FROM tablename ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

will select 10 questines at random under assumption the questine is stored under field questine