# Select X records randomly from a table for Y hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to select `10` records randomly from a table for `24 hours` the statement should return the same set for 24 hours

```
SELECT * FROM tableX LIMIT 10
```

I think i can use the `MMDDYY` as an input for an algorithm that would take 1 input and return the same set of data for that input. and use that in `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` then each day the select will return different data for the next 24 hours.

*for example:*

I have a table called `news` i want to be able to select `10 Random news` but i don't want the values to change every time the user refresh the page, i want the same news to appear for 24 hours. and next day it will change to another set of random news.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  I, for one, don't know what "select 10 records randomly from a table for 24 hours" means.

Comment: I added an example @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779585/select-random-rows-from-mysql-table), you can select random records from a table with:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

According to [MySql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), the function RAND() can take a seed as an argument.

So you should use:

```
 SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND(yyyymmdd) LIMIT 10;
```

where `yyyymmdd` is an integer representing the date.

Comment: yes i guess seeding the date solves the problem ! Thanks !