# How do I randomly select a row from a database?

Tags: mysql, database, random

I've currently entered 10 links into a csv file and uploaded. the column is called links and the table is called landmarks.
I've only ever selected things from the database rather than randomly generating a link.
I want to have a button on my page that you click and it can randomly select a link from the database. How do I do that, and then how do I make it so that when it is randomly generated that page will then open?

Comment: A CSV file is not a mysql database...

Comment: that's just the file I used to upload my links into the database

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting Random Rows in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283640/selecting-random-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add: `order by rand()`
to your query or you can use a PHP loop to take the 10 data points from your db into an array then use `rand(0,9)` to get a random ID from your array to output.