# Selecting random rows with MySQL

Tags: mysql, random

I saw many topics about this subject and I have been unsuccessful in understanding how to do it.

For example, if I have this table:

```
+------+-------+-------+
| id   | name  | class |
+------+-------+-------+
|    5 | test  | one   | 
|   10 | test2 | one   | 
|   12 | test5 | one   | 
|    7 | test6 | two   | 
+------+-------+-------+
```

and I want to show only X random rows from class "one", how can I do that?

**NOTE**: it's a big table, so I don't want to use `ORDER BY RAND`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [quick selection of a random row from a large table in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211329/quick-selection-of-a-random-row-from-a-large-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `ORDER BY RAND()` solution that most people recommend doesn't scale to large tables, as you already know.

```
SET @r := (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable)));
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1 OFFSET ', @r);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

I cover this and other solutions in my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

---

If you want to do this with PHP, you could do something like this (not tested):

```
<?php
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable")
$row = $result->fetch_row(); 
$count = $row[0]; 
$offset = mt_rand(0, $count);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1 OFFSET $offset");
...
$mysqli->commit();
```

Comment: Wow, this is high level of SQL. This is possible on PHP? and its the full code which I need to write on mysqli_query()?

Comment: Maybe it'd be usefull for that script to use [`mysqli::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: @Lumbendil: I do support using parameters where appropriate.  In the above example, the risk of SQL injection is minimal.  We know the value came from `rand()`, and that function only returns integers.

Comment: But, in case of wanting to retrieve multiple rows, the query could be executed multiple times without having to be analyzed on multiple ocasions.

Comment: For large tables will this be helpful, if I want to select one random row using order by rand():

select * from (select from large table where some condition) new_table order by rand() limit 0, 1;

Comment: @thekosmix, you shouldn't need to do that subquery, because regardless, the WHERE condition will limit the number of rows before it applies ORDER BY.

Comment: @BillKarwin rand() in PHP fails terribly with large datasets. I'd suggest using mt_rand() instead as the PHP docs claim it to be 4 times faster. I've found it to generate far more random results than rand().

Comment: With the PHP example, if it is possible that the count could shrink you should make sure to wrap the code in a SQL transaction.  If not you could end up selecting an offset that is larger than the returned set.

Comment: Nice! > impressive how "complex" it is using mysql, compared with sqlite3 method which gives you a nice integer to append on a query just right after a `select count(*) from table`

Answer (score 2):

```
select ID, NAME, CLASS
from YOURTABLE
where CLASS='one'
order by rand()
limit $x
```

ordering by `rand()` is not particularly efficient, but it's about the smallest/quickest way of doing it.

Comment: Notice: I use big table, and ORDER BY RAND() bom all rows in the table and its very slowly.

Comment: Yes, but it'd only be sorting the rows where class is 'one', not the entire table.

Comment: the class "one" can include thousands of rows.
By the way, can I get your messenger & skype?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `class`="one" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Notice: I use big table, and ORDER BY RAND() bom all rows in the table and its very slowly.