# mysql optimization: select a non previously selected random pair of different values from a column of unique values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, random

What would be the most efficient way to select a non previously selected pair of different random values from a column of unique (non repeated) values?

My current approach is (keeping every pair of values already associated in a separate "mytable_associations" table):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT id,count(*) AS associations_count FROM mytable 
 INNER JOIN mytable_associations 
 WHERE (myvalue=myvalue1 OR myvalue=myvalue2) 
 GROUP BY myvalue 
 HAVING associations_count<(SELECT count(*) FROM mytable)-1
 ORDER BY rand() limit 1
) mytable1 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT myvalue AS myvalue2 FROM mytable) mytable2
ON mytable1.myvalue1<>mytable2.myvalue2
WHERE
(
 SELECT myvalue1 FROM mytable_associations 
 WHERE
 myvalue1=mytable1.myvalue1 AND myvalue2=mytable2.myvalue2
 OR
 myvalue1=mytable2.myvalue2 AND myvalue2=mytable1.myvalue1
) IS NULL;
```

(And then of course update mytable_associations with this new association)

Which, as you can see, could hugely benefit from some optimization.

(Sorry about the poor indentation in the code, I really don't know how to indent mysql commands).

Can you  help me?

(P.S. This is my first question ever posted here: Sure I'm doing lots of things wrong and I'd understand the consequent flaming, but please don't be too hard on me ;) )

Comment: it seems a bit tricky to understand your query. Will you mind giving some insight into it, like explaining the different parts of the query and what they do? It would be great if you could give a dummy example of what do you want to achieve

Comment: basically it's two parts: first I choose a value not coupled with every other yet. I do that by SELECT RANDOM FROM mytable WHERE (SELECT number of associations for each value FROM associations_table) < (select count(*) from mytable)-1. If that is clear, you can see the rest is just selecting another value which is not already associated with that one in the associations_table: That's what the last two WHERE clauses are for.

Comment: just made an update to make the code less of a mess. Hope it's more readable now, but anyway look at the solution from Bill Karwin below, it's just what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any solution involving `order by rand()` is going to be inefficient.  For alternatives, see:

- My answer to [Selecting random rows with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6542113/20860)
- [Jan Kneschke on Order by RAND()](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)

To exclude numbers you've already picked, here's how I'd do it (this is pseudocode):

```
$c1 = SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT myvalue) FROM mytable
$c2 = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable_associations

$offset = ROUND( RAND() * ($c1 * ($c1-1) - $c2) )

SELECT v.* FROM (
  SELECT LEAST(m1.myvalue,my2.myvalue) AS myvalue1,
    GREATEST(m1.myvalue,my2.myvalue) AS myvalue2
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT myvalue FROM mytable) AS m1 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT myvalue FROM mytable) AS m2
    ON m1.myvalue <> m2.myvalue
) AS v
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable_associations AS a USING (myvalue1,myvalue2)
WHERE a.myvalue1 IS NULL
LIMIT 1 OFFSET $offset
```

By ensuring that myvalue1 < myvalue2, and storing them in that order in mytable_associations, you can simplify the join.

Comment: Not using order by rand() is definetly an improvement, but regarding point 3 I can't see how "WHERE a.myvalue1 IS NULL" avoids duplicity in choosing (a,b) and then (b,a), and also I get an error saying unknown column myvalue1 when I try to run it (Tried a.myvalue1 and mytable_associations.myvalue1 too, both turned it into a syntax error). Should I add both combinations to the association table to prevent that? What could I be doing wrong when I try to run your solution that leads to this errors?

Comment: (BTW, thank you very much for your quick reply: I'm just starting with SQL and sometimes it gets quite hard to figure out how to get things done properly)

Comment: Apologies, I misread the query in your original question and I misunderstood your table structure.  I have rewritten my answer.

Comment: Fantastic! Clear and efficient solution. You're a wiz, thank you very much for your help!