# Fastest way to get MYSQL random rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)
>   [Selecting random rows with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541644/selecting-random-rows-with-mysql)

MY Database has 4 Coloums NAME ID Email sex with 500k rows.

```
select * from table where sex='m';
```

I want to get 50 random rows where sex='M';
Which is the fastest method

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where sex='m'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: you have extra semi-column at the first row