# How to select efficently random Rows from a table without a numeric primary key

Tags: mysql, mysql5

What is the most efficent method to extract 1000 **random rows** from a table with 100.000.000 of records **without a numeric primary key**?

Using **ORDER BY RAND()** is excluded because highly inefficent.

Looking around the best method i found is the following:

```
SELECT key FROM (
    SELECT @cnt := COUNT( * ) +1, @lim := 1000 FROM table
)vars STRAIGHT_JOIN (
    SELECT r . * , @lim := @lim -1
    FROM table r
    WHERE (
        @cnt := @cnt -1
    )
    AND RAND( ) < @lim / @cnt
)i
```

is this the best possible method using MySQL 5 or is it possible to use more efficent code?

Comment: Whats wrong with 

`Select ket from table limit 1000`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting random rows with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541644/selecting-random-rows-with-mysql)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, i'm interested to the most generic case (i.e. alphanumeric primary key, primary key with more than one column etc.)
I found that many solutions already proposed work well only for particular cases i.e: autoincrement index with no holes or with even distribution of value.
Note: i want exactly 1000 rows, not solutions that give 1000 rows in 99,9% of cases.

Comment: @SashiKant it's not random. If i make the same query more than one time i will obtain very similar results.
Also i don't want Select key from table limit RAND()*(number_of_rows-1000),1000 because only the first row is really random.

Comment: @Alma Do Mundo please delete the "possible duplicate" flag

Answer (score -1):

In case you just want to get the first 1000 entries (but you can also declare an offset), you should look at Limit in MySql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: I don't want the first 1000 entries, i want 1000 random entries.