# Possible to display random ids from database in php on refresh?

Tags: php, mysql

So I had an idea where i would want other ids to display under the clients search term.

The basic idea what i wanted was to display RANDOMLY 5 other items from the database ( ids ) .

this was my attempt to do so:

```
<?php 
echo'<table width="200" border="0">
  <br>Other Items:&nbsp;<br></td><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">

<img src="http://rs-list.com/tools/items/'.(file_exists('items/'.$row['id'].'.png') ? $row['id'] : 0).'.png" class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="'.$row['name'].'"">
<p><a href="/html/codes/scrolling_images.cfm">'.$row['name'].'</a>.</p></marquee>';
?>
```

but of-course all this is going to do is echo the value of id, which in this case was 241. ( Photo : http://prntscr.com/7u40nm )

How can i echo the information for 5 other ids randomized on refresh?

Thanks for any help

Comment: pseudo query: select info from table where the id does not equal the item id limit five order by rand (every clause in this query is possible, just search for it)

Comment: check [selecting-random-rows-with-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541644/selecting-random-rows-with-mysql)

Comment: Ibrahim, do you perhaps have some malware on your computer? I've just reverted a spam edit from your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Sql query

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: not working, take a look at my full code here: http://pastebin.com/Y7d2zMb0

Comment: Got it working, thanks