# How to shuffle database value and display only 4

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried this but not working.

```
 $getPerson = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons LIMIT 0,15");
 shuffle($getPerson)//how to set limit for this?
```

Comment: i want to display only 4 from the database using shuffle. how is that possible? pls help. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND()` with `LIMIT 0,4`

```
SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,4
```

Comment: rand() will make it slow. are there any other alternatives besides rand()?

Comment: @Ivan no, I don't think so .. check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand

Comment: Check out the accepted answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541644/selecting-random-rows-with-mysql .  It looks like using the PHP `rand()` function might be faster than the mysqli `RAND()` function, at least for large databases.

Comment: how can it be... if you have to return a large number of records and then shuffle them, surely faster to return a small random set only

Comment: Using PDO might help but I'd still guess that PHP's rand() would be quicker