# generating 10 random id numbers form a table in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, random

i have an **id table** like this from **1 to 30**

```
|  id  |
|  1   |
|  2   |
|  3   |
|  4   |
|  5   |
|  .   |
|  .   |
|  .   |
|  30  |
```

what i want to do is get **10 random ids** from it in a string like this

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

what i figured out was

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3gTHLSTdFEac7dKbDcU43d/3

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3gTHLSTdFEac7dKbDcU43d/4

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(", ",
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids)),
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids)),
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids)),
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids)),
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids)),
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids)),
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids)),
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids)),
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids)),
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids))
    ) AS random_ids
```

is there a faster and more efficient way without using `ORDER BY RAND()`?

and is there also a way to make them unique like having a gap between them?

Comment: Can you allow duplicate ids within those 10?

Comment: @SalmanA yes and if there is a way for uniquness that would be good

Comment: If all you want is 10 random numbers between 1 and 30, what's the point of the table?

Comment: @Strawberry there can be more ids so the max id is variable

Comment: Still, I think I'd just find the max value and generate 10 random numbers in application code based off of that

Comment: @Strawberry i thought of that then thought that sql could possibly make an application like that in itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Updated fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3gTHLSTdFEac7dKbDcU43d/1

Edit: The question was updated to exclude `ORDER BY RAND()`.

You could do multiple queries. One to get the number of records in the database, and then select random values one at a time using `OFFSET`. I believe this would prevent a full table scan and be faster than a simple `ORDER BY RAND()` on a large data set.

Updated fiddle selecting one random id using this technique: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3gTHLSTdFEac7dKbDcU43d/5

```
SET @r := (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`)));
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT `id` FROM `table` LIMIT 1 OFFSET ', @r);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Credit: [Selecting random rows with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541644/selecting-random-rows-with-mysql/6542113#6542113)

Comment: i thought about using  ORDER BY RAND() but it uses a full scan and makes the query slow

Comment: This is HORRIBLY inefficient (for large tables) since it will first generate a random number for EVERY record in the table, then sort ALL records by that number and then only return the top 10. Imagine doing this on a multi-million records table... For a table with 30 records... meh.

Comment: Sure, but the question was quite specific that they had 30 ids. It runs in 80ms on db-fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ORDER BY RAND()` followed by `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') AS random_ids
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM t
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 10
) AS x
```

Comment: i would like not use `order by rand()` because it does a full scan maybe a shorter way to rewrite my query

Comment: I am afraid there isn't any other solution. If it is random then every row has same chance of getting selected.