# Random Row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, random

I am trying to get a random row in MySQL. Here is my approach:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE id = 
 (SELECT floor((max(id) - min(id) + 1) * rand()) + min(id)
  FROM users);
```

This can return an empty set when there are gaps in the ids. I am fine with that. However,

1. I don't have gaps and I still get **an empty set** rather frequently.
2. More disturbing: I will get **two or more results** every once in a while.

What is the reason for this strange behavior? How, do I get it right?

Note:

- the table is quite big (10^6 ... 10^7); I can't use any of the obvious, and known, solutions based on **random ordering** or even based on using **count()**.
- I'am stuck with MySQL, I don't care how it's done on the client side ruby/PHP/whatever.
- I tried to cast the floating types, but it did not help.
- The corresponding PostgreSQL variant (random instead of rand, and some type casts) works fine.

Comment: For how to get (fast) one random row from your table, see Karwin's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211329/quick-selection-of-a-random-row-from-a-large-table-in-mysql/213242#213242

Comment: You can also read this post by @Quassnoi: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/

Comment: Can you reproduce these results at the mysql prompt?  What are min(id), max(id) and the id chosen in those cases?  Can you cut down your data set to a smaller size and reproduce the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This avoids repeated evaluation of `random()` during the aggregation and should be faster, too, as `min(id)` and `random()` are only evaluated once.

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM   users u
      ,(SELECT min(id) AS min_id, max(id) AS max_id FROM users) x
WHERE  u.id > (floor((x.max_id - x.min_id + 1) * rand()) + x.min_id)
LIMIT  1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this is because `RAND()` is being evaluated for every row in the USERS table in the main query. I suggest:

```
SELECT u1.* 
from users u1,
     (SELECT floor((max(id) - min(id) + 1) * rand())  + min(id) lid from users) u2
WHERE u1.id > u2.lid
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT t.* FROM
  users t,
  (SELECT @id := (FLOOR((MAX(id) - MIN(id) + 1) * RAND()) + MIN(id)) FROM users) t2
WHERE
  t.id = @id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY rand() limit 1;
```

Will return a random row.

Comment: OP did explain that their tables are very large, which makes this query very slow.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE id >= (SELECT floor((max(id) - min(id) - 1) * rand())  + min(id) from users)
LIMIT 1
```

or similar?

Pretty much it should limit you to one result, and if it hits a gap (somehow), then it'll just take the next available one.