# Postgresql: Random and count in one query

Tags: postgresql, random

I use Postgresql 9.1. I have a table and I would like to get two things done in one query:

First: select one random sample row:

```
select * from table order by random() limit 1;
```

Second: count the number of rows the sample was selected from:

```
select count(1) from table;
```

Since a proper random() function has to know about all rows, I wonder if there is a way to get both results in one query.

I am guessing for something link:

```
select count(1), first.* from table order by random();
```

but i don't really know how to do it.

So I want a random row and the total number of rows.

Thanks for any ideas.

Steve

Comment: So you want a random row and the total number of rows ?

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297396/quick-random-row-selection-in-postgres which has interesting answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl) AS ct
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  1;
```

If the table is huge and performance is an issue, there are tricks to speed up the random selection. Having a serial column without gaps would help a lot with that ...

If that is for you, have a look at this related answer: [Random Row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095508/random-row-in-mysql/8099961#8099961)
Works in PostgreSQL, too. Only substitute  `random()` for `rand()`.

BTW, the `random()` function works absolutely independent of the number of rows.

---

Here is a variant that produces the same with only one sequential scan:

```
SELECT *, count(*) OVER () AS ct
FROM   ef.adr
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  1;
```

A quick test with a table of 5k rows was slower, though.
Another one with a table of 400k rows shows a similar result. slightly slower. Window functions can be performance hogs. And count(*) is known to be rather slow for large tables in PostgreSQL, because every tuple has to be visited.

Index-only scans ("covering indexes") has recently been implemented in the devel version of 9.2. So we are in for a speedup with the next version here. More about that in a [related post on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql/7541#7541):

In the meantime, 230 ms for the 400k table is not too bad.

Comment: UPDATE: On PG 9.4 this is really running faster (compared to PG 9.1 which I was using when you answered my question)