# How do you get the row returned by a SQL query that includes PREPARE and EXECUTE in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How do you get the row returned by [this SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211329/quick-selection-of-a-random-row-from-a-large-table-in-mysql/213242#213242) using PHP:

```
SET @r := (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable)));
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT ', @r, ', 1');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Setting `$query` equal to the above and then doing the usual `mysql_query($query)` is **not** returning any results.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this to see if it works

```
mysql_query('SET @r := (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable)));');
mysql_query('SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT ', @r, ', 1');');
$resource = mysql_query('PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;EXECUTE stmt1;');
```

Dont forget to escape the sql in the second instruction