# Is there is any way to get the select Random Records using query from table in mySql

Tags: mysql

Is there is any way to get the select Random Records using query from table in mySql.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142242/what-is-the-best-way-to-pick-a-random-row-from-a-table-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE RAND() < 0.5
```

change the percentage to include more or less records. add a `LIMIT` clause to, well, limit to a maximum number of records