# Random row, but with next and previous button

Tags: php, sql, random, image

I have a MySQL database with pictures within it. When a user comes to my page I want to show him random picture and from then he can go to the next or previous picture (not random)

Database example

```
id | picture 
11 | foto1.gif
12 | foto2.gif
16 | foto3.gif
23 | foto4.gif
66 | foto5.gif
```

How can I make something like that with PHP and SQL? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to pick a random row from a table in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142242/what-is-the-best-way-to-pick-a-random-row-from-a-table-in-mysql)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The linked question does not mention retrieving the next/previous entry.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ORDER BY rand()` in your query to get the random item.

To retrieve the next/previous item (by id), use this:

```
WHERE id < current_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1   (for prev)
WHERE id > current_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1   (for next)
```

Comment: Ok, but what clickable link can I make to go to the next or prev picture

Comment: You add something like `go=next` or `go=prev` to the query string and then create an appropriate WHERE statement in your PHP code.

Comment: Aha, so it seems to go without saying that the currently displayed picture's ID should somehow make it to the query string as well...

Comment: It doesn't work, because when random will give id 66, you can't go to the next picture...

Comment: Then check for this case and return the image with the lowest id in that case

Comment: Ok, but I don't know what the highest number is, users can upload new pictures

Comment: you don't need to know it. simply test if your query did not return any rows.