# ORDER BY RAND causing very high load

Tags: php, sql

I have the following query

```
$samecars = $this->QueryResult("SELECT * FROM carads where STATUS='1' and DEL='0' 
and TITLE !='' and IMAGE1 != '' and IMAGE1 != '-1' and PRICE BETWEEN $pricelow 
and $pricehigh order by RAND() LIMIT 0,3");
```

When I remove `RAND()` the query is executed almost instantly, if I add the `RAND()` it takes about 10-30 seconds.

There are about 1 million rows in the table carads.
I need RAND() in order to use random displaying.

More details:

`QueryResult` looks like this

```
public function QueryResult($strQuery) {
    $this->connector();
    $query = mysqli_query($this->link, $strQuery);
    $arr = array();
    if ($query) {
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
            array_push($arr, $result);
        }
    }
    $this->close();
    return $arr;
}
```

ALSO I tried add in SQL the following example command

```
SELECT * FROM carads where STATUS='1' and DEL='0' 
and TITLE !='' and IMAGE1 != '' and IMAGE1 != '-1' and PRICE BETWEEN 8000 
and 15000 order by RAND() LIMIT 0,3"
```

and RAND() is highlighted red and when i execute it through `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"' at line 3`

Comment: @MitchWheat And how can i overcome this?

Comment: In your sql there's no need for final quote `"`.

Comment: This is a dup as Alma pointed out. Although the referenced question deals with selecting only one row, the same principles apply in this case.

Comment: You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/4329447/1961059

Comment: @u_mulder oups, yes indeed, i executed again, and it takes 43.6503 sec in order to execute it, any ideas?

Comment: use a search engine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142242/what-is-the-best-way-to-pick-a-random-row-from-a-table-in-mysql , etc

Comment: There's a book called SQL antipatterns that devotes an entire chapter to the order by rand() problem.  Long story short there's no entirely ideal solution, but almost anything is better than using rand() as an ordering clause.

Comment: How about `LIMIT RAND(), 3` ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany this would result in three random but consecutive entries... Furthermore you will need to bound-check this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Russian roulette sampling**

The reason why `RAND()` causes problems is because all rows of the table are queried instead of for instance the first three. Furthermore sorting takes some time.

An idea to speed up processing is using Russian roulette sampling:

```
SELECT * FROM carads where STATUS='1' and DEL='0' and TITLE !='' and IMAGE1 != '' and IMAGE1 != '-1' and PRICE BETWEEN $pricelow and $pricehigh AND RAND() < 0.001 LIMIT 0,3
```

where 0.001 is fairly small. The problem with this method is that items will not be picked uniformly (first items have more chance). Furthermore the probability should depend on the size of the table (so occasionally, an administration tool should recalculate the probability). However it is a pragmatic solution to the problem.

**2. PHP does (most) of the work**

Since there are only three rows, you could execute the following procedure:

1. First query the database to find the number of rows
2. Generate three distinct random numbers between 0 and the number of rows (exclusive)
3. Query the three rows and process the data.

Comment: I added 0.01 and now it's processing it in 0.03 secs from 45 secs. and they are random, 10 refreshes and never encountered same car.

Comment: "10 refreshes and never encountered same car" - hardly a definitive test of uniformity!

Comment: As I claim in the answer, the items are indeed not uniform: the first elements have more chance to be picked than the last ones. In engineering however, there is the law of "conservation of misery". Sometimes one needs to sacrifice some quality to make it feasible.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I was referring to user3140607: I'm aware of this technique: http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/t-sql-generating-random-numbers-random.html

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why the query is executing slowly is that when using an aggregate function like rand(), time functions and etc... prevents the query to be cached. So a good practice is to try and not to use these kind of functions in the SQL query and pass it with php like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table order by " . rand();
```

instead of

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table order by RAND()";
```

Hope it was useful.

Regards

Comment: I don't see how this might work. The resulting query becomes for instance `SELECT * FROM table order by 0.75165156`. That means that all the rows have the same order-attribute. Therefore SQL will probably yield the original order (or at least a deterministic one).